# "E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing " error on jobs created in gitlab pipelines

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed gitlab and gitlab-runner locally on my Server(of course in separate servers).

Now I want to run a simple job in the pipeline like this :

```
    stages:
  - test_ftp_connection

test_ftp_connection:
  stage: test_ftp_connection
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ftp
    - ftp -d -n -v 157.96.582.42 <<EOF
      user username password
      passive
      ls
      bye
      EOF
  only:
    - main  # Adjust the branch or tag where you want to run this test
```

But whenever I run that job I get this error :

```
    Running with gitlab-runner 16.5.0 (853330f9)
  on aloghesti-runner v5YDsxuaz, system ID: r_qfj6n9LoVjcy
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on ec3829a0008a...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/v5YDsxuaz/0/aloghesti/ci-cd-test-project/.git/
Checking out 3e462ed5 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ apt-get update -qy
Reading package lists...
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

main error is in this line :

```
$ apt-get update -qy
Reading package lists...
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Note that I have installed the gitlab runner via docker.

I have checked various methods and have taken help from Google, but my problem has not been solved.